# Using React change element behavior in UI based on screen width

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, resize, chakra-ui

I'll write some information about my project.

**Framework:** NextJs, below version 13
**UI Framework:** ChakraUI (Using predefined components, mostly Flex)

**The idea is as following**: I have tested and determined what screen sizes should require element behavior changes on the UI and decided to write code that will facilitate that functionality.

Doing things like, I'll avoid writing @media logic for every page/component, since I already know at which screen sizes changes will happen.

This is pretty vague, so I'll add some context:

```
    if (typeof window === "undefined") return 6;
    const windowWidth: number = window.innerWidth;

    if (windowWidth <= 600) return 2;
    else if (windowWidth <= 900) return 3;
    else if (windowWidth <= 1200) return 4;
    else if (windowWidth <= 1400) return 5;

    return 6;
```

As you can see, basically I've decided that for some breakpoint widths, a number will be returned. Using this I can influence, for instance, how many items are displayed, in a row, on the screen, or what the width of an element should be etc.

Example of usage for displaying how many items should be in a line:

**`width={`${Math.floor(100 / displayItemsCount)}%`}`**

Or here is an example of influencing the width of an item:

**width={displayItemsCount <= 2 ? '90%' : displayItemsCount <= 4 ? '70%' : '50%'}**

**Note**: To avoid confusion, **displayItemsCount** is the value that the above block of code returns.

**Disclaimer**: Since doing things like I imagined has caused me to do a lot of testing, research and has caused me issues, I'm also open for suggestions that are of the type: **"This thinking is wrong, a better solution would be ...".**

I know there a billion answers here regarding this issue, but I think they don't cover everything that I need here. Some of the code is from my SO research as well.

**I'll write here some groundwork so that it's clear what's currently being used.**

Firstly, I wanted a debounce present, so that the code doesn't get called on every pixel change. This is mostly for when the user is resizing the screen while using the Inspect Element tool.

```
function debounce(fn: Function, ms: number) {
    let timeoutId: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>
    return function (this: any, ...args: any[]) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        timeoutId = setTimeout(() => fn.apply(this, args), ms);
    }
};

function determineDisplayItemsCount() {
    if (typeof window === "undefined") return 6;
    const windowWidth: number = window.innerWidth;

    if (windowWidth <= 600) return 2;
    else if (windowWidth <= 900) return 3;
    else if (windowWidth <= 1200) return 4;
    else if (windowWidth <= 1400) return 5;

    return 6;
};
```

**Debounce** calls the code whenever some amount time has passed after the screen was resized, while **determineDisplayItemsCount** returns a value based on the current screen size.

Disregard the naming of the **determineDisplayItemsCount**, this is a remnant of some old use-case, so it will be changed.

The second thing that I wanted, is that this code is present in a hook, so that it is easy to use.

```
function useDisplayItemsCount() {

    const [displayItemsCount, setDisplayItemsCount] = useState<number>(determineDisplayItemsCount());

    useEffect(() => {
        const debounceHandleResize = debounce(
            function handleResize() {
                let count: number = determineDisplayItemsCount();
                if (count != displayItemsCount)
                    setDisplayItemsCount(count);
            }, 250);
        window.addEventListener('resize', debounceHandleResize)

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('resize', debounceHandleResize)
        }
    }, []);
    
    return displayItemsCount;
}
```

As you can see, in the **useEffect** the **handleResize** gets called whenever the screen changes width, but after an additional 250ms passes by.
I also added if the new **count** is the same as the current **displayItemsCount**, then the state won't change.

The result is that I can go into any page/component now and go something like:
`const displayItemsCount = useDisplayItemsCount();`. Then use that value for whatever I need.

***Issues***

- First issue

When **useDisplayItemsCount** gets called, the initial value of **displayItemsCount** will be set based on the **determineDisplayItemsCount** function.
This causes a *hydration error*, since I have to use **window** and the component wasn't mounted yet. My thinking was that if I had the following line in **determineDisplayItemsCount**:
`if (typeof window === "undefined") return 6;`, I'd avoid the *hydration error*, but nope it's still there.

- Second issue

So I decided heck, let's just have it so the initial value is 6:
`const [displayItemsCount, setDisplayItemsCount] = useState<number>(6);`, but that results in the fact that when the page is loaded from a phone, aka smaller screen, **useDisplayItemsCount** returns 6 at the start. The **useEffect** inside the hook gets called only after the user scrolls a little bit on the page, or interacts with something.

**I guess my question is, how to make this code work correctly, without causing a hydration error?**

As stated, a great answer would also be an alternative approach.

**Note**: Probably worth stating that using Grid doesn't really solve my problems, since I want to avoid writing @media in all cases.

Comment: If Chakra UI is used, any reasons not to use its [breakpoints](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/responsive-styles#the-object-syntax) based styles? It accepts customized breakpoints in theme, and it also provides a [hook](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/hooks/use-breakpoint-value) that returns a conditional breakpoint value based on window resizing, which also has a fallback value for SSR if needed.

Comment: @JohnLi totally didn't know this existed. I'll give it a whirl. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With CSS grid, you actually don't need to have a single media query to create grid columns that are fully responsive.  Using the `minmax` function, with `auto-fit` or `auto-fill` you can set a minimum and maximum size for your grid items. The number of columns will automatically adjust to fit or fill according to the space available.

Run the code snippet below and then use the full screen link to see what I mean.

```css
/*
With CSS Grid, you can create a fully responsive grid in two declarations on the parent.  
*/

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: .75rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(175px, 1fr));
}

.item {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: grid;
  font: bold 2rem sans-serif;
  place-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @JohnLi and @jme11 for the information. A combination of your answers was the solution for me.

I'm now using Chakra breakpoints to handle the styling on the components, while grid is being used to display the location.

This was really helpful. If I could I'd accept both answers!

Comment: Please add answers in the answer section, nothing else, you can thank them in the comment section. You can add the final answer under your own question.